# Accessing JSON parsed object (works with trace but not without...)

Tags: javascript, json, data-access

I'm facing a weird problem after parsing a JSON file. I access the data and can use it only if I use "trace" at the right place ! When I comment the trace line I get "undefined"... Is it a problem of execution order of my code or maybe a problem passing the string argument ?

Thanks in advance for looking for a solution, this problem is very frustrating!!

Here is my code :

//index.js

```
var language={};

var resourceManager = {};


$(document).ready(function(){
loading();
});



function loading() {

$.ajaxSetup({'beforeSend': function(xhr){
if (xhr.overrideMimeType)
    xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain");
    }
});

$.getJSON("json/lang_french.json", function(data) {
      language = data;
});

setTitle();
}

function setTitle()
{

 var title = resourceManager.getString("welcome");
 var query = document.getElementById('title');
 query.textContent = title;
}

resourceManager.getString = function(str)
{

    //alert(str);//if I uncomment this line, the whole code works...
    return language[str];//when the "alert" is commented, return undefined !!!
};
```

Here is the JSON file : lang_french.json

```
{
"welcome" : "Bienvenue",
"goodbye" : "Au revoir"
}
```

and the HTML file, index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <style>img{ height: 100px; float: left; }</style>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="title">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100%, but I'd guess that what is happening is that the asynchronous $.getJSON call hasn't completed by the time it gets to "return language[str]" (AKA a race condition). Putting the "alert" in must give it enough time to complete the call.

Try putting "setTitle" in the callback for $.getJSON eg:

```
$.getJSON("json/lang_french.json", function(data) {
      language = data;
      setTitle();
});
```

That means it will wait to make that call until language is actually set, rather than being the empty object {}.